# Case statement returning zero

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want blank as an output instead of zero or NULL as output for this query

```
select ID,
CASE WHEN VOL LIKE '%[1-9]%'
      AND TYPE IN ('P','Q') THEN 20
ELSE ' '
END AS QUAN
```

OUTPUT NOW IS :

```
ID     QUAN
F234   20
G345   20
R445   0
T334   0
```

DESIRED OUTPUT :

```
ID     QUAN
F234   20
G345   20
R445   
T334
```

tried with NULL still getting 0 in Quan column. please help

Comment: ...why?  If something is labelled what I take to be `"Quantity"`, I'm _really_ going to be expecting a numeric value (say, `0`), or null, **not** string data.  Is `VOL` (`Volume`?) being stored as string data?  Does the column hold anything other than digits?  Why the blanket use of `20`?

Comment: Yes, @clockwork-muse, you had a point. But, there is other quantity column which calculates the volume in numeric, but QUAN just hold codes as 20 ,30,etc., and ''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `case` expression has to return one type, but two different types are specified (an integer and a string):

```
select ID,
       (CASE WHEN VOL LIKE'%[1-9]%' AND TYPE IN ('P','Q') THEN 20
             ELSE ' '
        END) AS QUAN
```

The string is turned to the integer value of `0`.

Normally, in SQL, you would just use `NULL`:

```
select ID,
       (CASE WHEN VOL LIKE '%[1-9]%' AND TYPE IN ('P','Q') THEN 20
        END) AS QUAN
```

However, in this case, if you *really* want strings, make the `20` `'20'`:

```
select ID,
       (CASE WHEN VOL LIKE '%[1-9]%' AND TYPE IN ('P','Q') THEN '20'
             ELSE ' '
        END) AS QUAN
```